# If Loop returning Index Values instead of Vector Character Values

Tags: r

From the dataset below:

```
         Referee      Tca
1       A D'Urso 2.733333
2       A Davies 3.529412
3       A Haines 2.722222
4       A Madley 3.407407
5     A Marriner 3.640000
6       A Taylor 3.603448
7      A Woolmer 3.222222
8       B Malone 1.636364
9        C Berry 3.800000
10     C Boyeson 3.800000
```

I'm trying to create a simple loop that gives me the names of the referees with Tca > 4.

The loop code is:

```
test <- NULL
for (i in c(1:length(gio$Referee))) {
if(gio$Tca[i] > 4){
    test[i] <- gio$Referee[i]
 }
}
```

However this doesn't return me a list of names but a list of indexes:

How will I be able to get the list of referees instead of indexes?

Comment: pretty simple in base R: `gio$Referee[gio$Tca >4]` , you can then save it to another `data.frame`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
as.character(with(gio,Referee[Tca>3]))
[1] "A Davies"   "A Madley"   "A Marriner" "A Taylor"   "A Woolmer"  "C Berry"    "C Boyeson"
```

(I have chosen `Tca > 3` here because your criterion `Tca > 4` results in an empty vector with the given sample data).

**data**

```
gio <- read.table(text="Referee Tca
                   'A D\\'Urso' 2.733333
                     'A Davies' 3.529412
                     'A Haines' 2.722222
                     'A Madley' 3.407407
                   'A Marriner' 3.640000
                     'A Taylor' 3.603448
                    'A Woolmer' 3.222222
                     'B Malone' 1.636364
                      'C Berry' 3.800000
                   'C Boyeson'  3.800000", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling your dataframe df you can simply use dplyr, filtering your df doing something like this:

```
  library(dplyr)
  filtered_df = filter(df, Tca > 4)
```

Comment: OP appears to be asking for the names only

Answer (score 0):

**Because Referencing a factor variable gives level of factor and not factor value**

The reason  you are getting indices instead of names is because `gio$Referee` is stored as a factor and when you refer a factor using `factor[any index]` you get index and not the factor value.

To get the factor value append `as.character`

```
test <- NULL
for (i in c(1:length(gio$Referee))) {
    if(gio$Tca[i] > 3){
        test[i] <- as.character(gio$Referee[i])
    }
}
```

Note : I have modified condition to greater than 3.

this will give output as

```
test
 [1] NA           "A Davies"   NA           "A Madley"   "A Marriner" "A Taylor"  
 [7] "A Woolmer"  NA           "C Berry"    "C Boyeson"
```

Now these NA's are because you initialized with NULL and are putting only values at indices which satisfies your condition. A better for loop will be

```
test <- character()
for (i in c(1:length(gio$Referee))) {
    if(gio$Tca[i] > 3){
        test<-append(test,as.character(gio$Referee[i]))
    }
}
```

Here I initialized test with empty character array and I am appending those values from `gio$Referee` which satisfies my condition. This gives output as

```
test
[1] "A Davies"   "A Madley"   "A Marriner" "A Taylor"   "A Woolmer"  "C Berry"   
[7] "C Boyeson"
```

Above All as everyone has said

**You dont need loop to do this**

subset your data frame as

```
gio$Referee[gio$Tca>3]
```

This means give me `Referee` from `gio` where `gio$Tca` is greater than `3`